# How to fix the error of running remmina in xephyr on linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, remmina, xephyr

How to fix the error of running remmina in xephyr on linux mint?

Terminal commands:

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x720 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &
DISPLAY=:1 remmina
```

Terminal output:

```
remmina-Message: 10:06:46.390: Remmina does not log all output statements. Turn on more verbose output by using "G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all" as an environment variable.
More info available on the Remmina wiki at:
https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
Load modules from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/remmina/plugins
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
The glibsecret secret plugin has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin

(org.remmina.Remmina:15516): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:06:46.455: cannot open display: :1
[1]+  Completed        Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x720 -br -reset -terminate :1 2> /dev/null
```